# What is the correct way to sample from a large dataset with several years of data?

Tags: machine-learning, sampling

I'm a student doing a machine learning project. I'm using the Lending Club Dataset 2007-2018 to predict loan default. The original dataset contains over 2 million rows. I want use a sample from it to train the model, since I have limited processing capability. What is the correct way to sample from the dataset?

Comment: At random, randomly.